# jquery Checkboxes have they been checked?

Tags: php, jquery

When init my form it looks like something like this:

```
                <?php if ($row['active'] == 1) { ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" checked="checked" value="1"></td>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="0"></td>
    <?php } ?>
```

my jQuery to grab all active is:

```
'active': $("input[name='active\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()
```

However, this don't give me the value I need. I need the value 0 if it's unchecked and 1 if it's checked, stored in an array like in the jQuery above. But my check fails to change this.

SOLUTION: `'active': $("input[name='active\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).is(':checked');}).get()`

Comment: post your solution as answer or delete your question it that was trivial

Comment: You can use `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(':checked')`.